Any commands to switch to the window on the far left or right?
Let's say I have a grid of 3x2 windows open and I am focused on the bottom right one. I want to switch to the one on the bottom left with one command, not move left twice. Vice versa as well. There's <C-W>t and <C-W>b which switch to the top or bottom windows, but I want to move to the far left and right. H and L moves the position of the window, when I want to switch which window focus.

All the commands for moving the cursor to another window are listed under :help window-move-cursor, including the ones you give as example: <C-w>t for the top-left window and <C-w>b for the bottom-right window. There obviously is no equivalent for the top-right and bottom-left windows so the only possibilities that don't imply writing a lot of fragile vimscript are those provided by @friedrich. If those don't suit you, look for a plugin that solves your problem.

In Vim, you often prepend a count to your commands. This is no exception. Use <C-W>2h to move two windows to the left, giving your bottom left window focus.
You can also click the respective window with the mouse; assuming you have :set mouse to any working value.

:wincmd can take a count, and even $ is accepted.
As such, :$wincmd l/$wincmd j and :$wincmd j/k seem to be a good start. From there any mapping where you combine them should do.
e.g.
:nnoremap <silent> <c-w>B :<c-u>$wincmd j<cr>:$wincmd h<cr>

